# Can rectangular matrix be a triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused with what is mentioned here:

[image]

*Linear algebra and its applications-David C. Lay*

**Update:** This question may be closed. My comment to the answer below clarifies my misunderstanding with the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but to answer your title question: a triangular matrix is a special kind of square matrix, while a rectangular matrix is a matrix for which horizontal and vertical dimensions are not the same (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularMatrix.html)

Comment: Actually I was not understanding the text. The matrices he used are augmented matrices of a 3-var 3-eqn system. So, only the first three columns may be considered, which gives an order 3 square matrix. Now I get it.